# Different versions of ODAC causing error in C# application (local Vs Server)

Tags: c#, odp.net, odac

I have built an application using C#. I had referenced ODAC version 4.121.2.0.
When I deployed my application on the server, the application failed with error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or asse
>   mbly 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b4
>   83f429c47342'. This assembly was compiled for a different processor.

The server only has 4.121.1.0 installed.

What do I need to do to make application work? Things I tried:

```
 1. In the .csproj <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>

 <Private>False</Private>

 2. I tried copying over the ODAC version (4.121.2.0) in the bin solution directory(of the server), it wouldn't work.
 3. I tried removing all ODAC dlls in folder, so that it can find out older version and use that for functionality.
```

I do not want to install older version on my local and then - I have tried this in the past and I ended up uninstalling all the versions.

Possible duplicates:
[Having two ODP.NET (ODAC) versions in the same server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503962/having-two-odp-net-odac-versions-in-the-same-server)

[How do I get an older version of OracleClient to work locally with .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35275447/how-do-i-get-an-older-version-of-)
oracleclient-to-work-locally-with-net

But these links didn't provide solution for my problem.

Comment: That's not a slight difference. Your code was built expecting a newer assembly but found an *older* one instead. Deploy the correct file

Comment: BTW `BadImageFormatException` is typically thrown when 32 and 64 bit assemblies get mixed. That's a huge difference. Deploy the *correct* assembly. If you can't control which version of ODAC is used, find out the server's version and recompile your code using that version

Comment: I have removed 'Slightly' from the question (sorry, I was too tired).
I made 2 changes 
   - reference path changed from my Oracle Home to use GAC.
  - modified Proj to use 64 bit dll.
It worked after above 2 changes. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the error your are getting is not related to a dependency versioning issue. A `BadImageFormatException` usually gets thrown when there are `32Bit`/`64Bit` incompatibilities between the entry point (i.e. `exe` file) and one of the dependencies.

Try playing with the target platform when you compile the project(s) (`Any CPU`/`x86`/`x64` and the `Prefer 32-Bit` project property).

Hope it helps!

Comment: The version difference itself would case an exception. Looks like the OP deployed the wrong version *and* bitness

Comment: I made 2 changes 
   - reference path changed from my Oracle Home to use GAC.
   - modified Proj to use 64 bit dll.
It worked after above 2 changes. Thanks to both of you ... Itay Podhajcer and Panagiotis Kanavos

Comment: Forgot to mention - On the server the Oracle Home was V 4.121.1.0 , but it had the 64 bit dll present in the GAC.

Do let me know if I need to mention anything else (if my response had opened up any question)