# How to determine which oracle driver is used by BizTalk Oracle Adapter

Tags: oracle, driver, adapter, biztalk

I have 2 different oracle drivers in my system installed, both 32 and 64 bit - How can I specify and select proper one with BizTalk Oracle Send Port?

I currently use BizTalk 2020 but question is general.

Comment: did you install two different ODAC in your system ?

Comment: @RobertoHernandez Yes

Answer (score 0):

The admin console always uses the 32 bit.

The port will use either the 32 bit or the 64 bit depending on the configuration of the host instance it is running under.  Generally you would want that on a 64 bit host instance.

Generally with Microsoft the latest version of any DLL would be used except where it is pinned to use a specific version.

Comment: Ok but i have 2 different version of odac installed, what then?

Comment: @PiotrGrudzień I suppose you could use something like Process Monitor to see which one it loads https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation I managed to find something worth publishing

This is summary from these articles and sites:

[Architecture overview of the BizTalk Adapter for Oracle Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/adapters-and-accelerators/adapter-oracle-database/architecture-overview-of-the-biztalk-adapter-for-oracle-database)

[Installing and Configuring Oracle Data Provider for .NET](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e23174/InstallODP.htm#ODPNT151)

[Stackoverflow question about 2 different ODAC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503962/having-two-odp-net-odac-versions-in-the-same-server/2511074#2511074)

[MSDN Site explain how dll is linked](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order?redirectedfrom=MSDN#search-order-for-desktop-applications)

1. **This part is still unknown If someone have more insight on this please share.**
   WCFCustom Adapter with oracle binding uses Microsft Oracle DB Adapter (Microsoft.Adapters.OracleDB.dll) which invokes Oracle.DataAccess.dll in some version. What version of it  depends probably on 32 vs 64 bit host as mentioned by @Dijkgraaf ,
   system settings and bindings, being in GAC etc. as mentioned in [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503962/having-two-odp-net-odac-versions-in-the-same-server/2511074#2511074) [4](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order?redirectedfrom=MSDN#search-order-for-desktop-applications).
2. The Oracle.DataAccess.dll searches for dependent unmanaged DLLs (such as Oracle Client) based on the following order:

   a) Directory of the application or executable.

   b) DllPath setting specified by application config or web.config.

   c) DllPath setting specified by machine.config.

   d) DllPath setting specified by the Windows Registry :

   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Oracle\ODP.NET\version\DllPath
   32bit has separate HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\WOW6432Node\Oracle\ODP.NET\version\DllPath
   **In my case I found path to Oracle driver here in registry**

   e) Directories specified by the Windows PATH environment variable.